# How come the medium-offset-2 value does not apply

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm using zurb's foundation to build my website, and I have two action buttons in a callout.

Now I would like to have some space in between the two buttons upto tablet sized screens, so I've used a medium-offset- as class.

```
<div class="callout large">
    <div class="row column text-center">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
        <a href="#" class="button medium-2">Some Button</a>
        <a href="#" class="button medium-2 medium-offset-2 hollow">Another Button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the end-result just has the normal gutter space between the two buttons, and I can't figure out why the css for .button has higher priority than the margin applied by medium-offset-

Here is  a working example in jsfiddle which has the same issue. I also tried re-arranign  positions of button and medium-offset- positions in html to see if that affected, but no dice. https://jsfiddle.net/u356n5cs/

If I specifically target the buttons with say an id or .named_div > a 
, the result adds a space,  but then the entire thing is not exactly centered.

Comment: The O, if you haven't seen it yet, my answer below shows how to use the Foundation 6 grid to do what you are wanting: [link to answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865749/how-come-the-medium-offset-2-value-does-not-apply/36867579#36867579)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the margin of your `medium-offset-2` class is being explicitly overridden :

[image]

A quick glance shows that the `.button` class that is being applied to the same element appears to be the responsible party :

[image]

You could force the margin to be applied to the button by defining your own custom style like the following one to ensure it is applied properly :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 40em){
  .button.medium-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66667%;
  }
}
```

You can [see an example of this here](https://jsfiddle.net/1c9765sa/3/).

Comment: That does solve the problem, but how come  that is how  zurb has implemented this?  Is this something that needs be solved? (PS: Thanks)

Comment: I would assume that these offset and grid-based classes are more commonly used for "container" elements like `<div>` elements as opposed to the actual buttons themselves. You might consider wrapping each of your buttons within a `<div>` that contained two underlying elements styled with `medium-2` and `medium-offset-2` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `<div class="row column text-center">` is for a row with column width of 12 on the grid... so the grid width was already maxed. I altered your example by splitting the title row from the anchors and specifying the anchors as columns within a row having undefined column width and tried in your fiddle. Spreads them apart to the boundaries in medium screen width:

```
    <div class="callout large">
        <div class="columns row text-center">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
            <a href="#" class="button medium-2 columns">Some Button</a>
            <a href="#" class="button medium-2 medium-offset-2 hollow columns">Another Button</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```